# Figcaption prevents images from aligning inline

Tags: css, html, inline

I'm building a navigation box with 3 rows and 3 columns of images. My target was to add some text below each image. I came across 'figcaption' today and although it seams like the perfect tag, i can't seam to get it to display properly.

**The problem**
The images display properly 'inline' until I add the 'figcaption' tags. The text appears in block (i assume), below each image which is great.. but it also forces the next image onto a new line (Even though inline block has been applied to the parent container '').

The html that i'm using goes as follows..

```
<section class="menu">
<h1>Menu</h1>
<br /><br />
    <div>
    <a href=""><img src="img/image.png"><figcaption>Caption</figcaption></a>
    <a href=""><img src="img/image.png"><figcaption>Caption</figcaption></a>
    <a href=""><img src="img/image.png"><figcaption>Caption</figcaption></a>        
    </div>

        ***Div repeated twice***

</section>
```

And here is the css

```
.menu div {
    padding: 0;}
.menu li a{display: inline;}
.menu a img{
    width:32.1%; height:auto; 
    }
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bundaberg/DHM46/2/)

Thanks

Comment: Oh, interesting, I've never seen a `figcaption` tag before! It sounds like something yummy to eat...

Comment: It's worth noting that you have the selector `li a`, but there are no `li` tags in your markup, thus the style here isn't applied.

Comment: Thanks for that! Time to make a couple of amendments =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to MDN, `<figcaption>` needs to be inside a `<figure>` tag:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figcaption

Here's an updated HTML structure:

```
<section class="menu">
<h1>Menu</h1>
<br />
    <div>
        <figure>
            <a href="">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100">
            </a>
            <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <a href="">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100">
            </a>
            <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <a href="">
              <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100">
            </a>  
            <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>      
         </figure>
    </div>
</section>
```

and associated css:

```
.menu div {
    padding: 0;}
.menu figure {display: inline-block;
    width:100px;
}
.menu a img{
    height:auto; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DHM46/5/

Comment: Hey thanks, but the goal is to create a grid. The problem i am having is with aligning the three captioned images in a row.

Comment: Note that a figcaption must also be the first or last direct child of a figure. It is invalid for the figcaption to be the child of an `<a>` element as per your example.

Comment: @Alohci Good point, I've updated my example so it should validate